# UWP won't compile GetBufferFromString in Microsoft example for FileIO.WriteBufferAsync

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I'm trying to use WriteBufferAsync in the [Microsoft example for FileIO.WriteBufferAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.writebufferasync?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) but GetBufferFromString doesn't compile.

Ultimately, I want to write a byte buffer to an absolute file path.

This is a copy from the example...

```
try
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        IBuffer buffer = GetBufferFromString("Swift as a shadow");
        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
        // Perform additional tasks after file is written
    }
}
// Handle errors with catch blocks
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // For example, handle file not found
}
```

Comment: That code is excerpted from the full UWP sample on GitHub, [and here's the definition of GetBufferFromString](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/FileAccess/cs/Scenario4_WriteAndReadBytesInAFile.xaml.cs#L42).

Comment: A simpler version is `IBuffer GetBufferFromString(string str) => CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);` Works only for nonempty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GetBufferFromString doesn't compile.

@Raymond Chen's comments are very convincing. And he is the author of the UWP official code sample. The reason why [`GetBufferFromString`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/FileAccess/cs/Scenario4_WriteAndReadBytesInAFile.xaml.cs#L42) could not be compiled is you have not declared it.

```
private IBuffer GetBufferFromString(String str)
{
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            dataWriter.WriteString(str);
            return dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to write a byte buffer to an absolute file path.

For writing a buffer to an absolute file path, you could use [`PathIO.WriteBufferAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pathio.writebufferasync) method. Please note, you need make sure your file could be accessed within uwp. for example, if your file stored in picture library, you need add Picture capability. for more detail please refer UWP [file access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).